# Unable to use static method defined in another file of same package

Tags: java

Running Test.java throws error run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: 
    at algorithms.Test.main(Test.java:9)

Both files are present in same directory "algorithms" and `package algorithms` is also mentioned in the beginning of each file.

What is the issue in running main() of Test?

## Gcd.java file

```
package algorithms;

public class Gcd {

public static int ComputeGcd(int number1, int number2){
    if(number2 == 0){ return number1;}
    else{
         int remainder = number1 % number2;
         return ComputeGcd(number2,remainder);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 32;
    int b = 12;
    System.out.println(ComputeGcd(a,b));

} 
}
```

## Test.java file

```
package algorithms;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 32;
    int b = 12;
   System.out.println(ComputeGcd(a,b));

}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using:

```
System.out.println(Gcd.ComputeGcd(a,b));
```

instead of:

```
System.out.println(ComputeGcd(a,b));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the class:

```
System.out.println(GCD.ComputeGcd(a,b));
```